# Why scheduled Jenkins builds won't start next time after aborting them?

Tags: jenkins

Somehow, when a scheduled Jenkins build is manually aborted, it won't start next time automatically as usual, unless I initiate the build manually. Then, the next time, it works as usual. Why is that? Why won't scheduled builds start next time after aborting them?

Comment: what do you mean by automatically? git push? which plugin do you use? or just poll scm?

Comment: Under the pipeline configuration you can schedule when builds have to start periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jenkins doesnt have such logic (do not trigger after abort)

and i tested it works for me as well with plugins

```
bouncycastle API Plugin 2.29
Caffeine API Plugin 3.1.6-115.vb_8b_b_328e59d8
Credentials Binding Plugin  631.v861c06d062b_4
Credentials Plugin  1271.v54b_1c2c6388a_
Durable Task Plugin 513.vc48a_a_075a_d93
Folders Plugin  6.815.v0dd5a_cb_40e0e
Groovy  453.vcdb_a_c5c99890
Instance Identity   173.va_37c494ec4e5
Ionicons API    56.v1b_1c8c49374e
JavaBeans Activation Framework (JAF) API    1.2.0-6
JavaMail API    1.6.2-9
Locale plugin   314.v22ce953dfe9e
Pipeline: API   1251.vd4889a_b_0a_065
Pipeline: Groovy    3731.ve4b_5b_857b_a_d3
Pipeline: Groovy Libraries  656.va_a_ceeb_6ffb_f7
Pipeline: Nodes and Processes   1278.v94b_dc2b_50c6f
Pipeline: SCM Step  415.v434365564324
Pipeline: Step API  639.v6eca_cd8c04a_a_
Pipeline: Supporting APIs   848.v5a_383b_d14921
Plain Credentials Plugin    143.v1b_df8b_d3b_e48
SCM API Plugin  676.v886669a_199a_a_
Script Security Plugin  1251.vfe552ed55f8d
SSH Credentials Plugin  305.v8f4381501156
Structs Plugin  324.va_f5d6774f3a_d
Trilead API Plugin  2.84.v72119de229b_7
Variant Plugin  59.vf075fe829ccb
```

and core `2.401.3`

try to upgrade jenkins core to latest, also might be related to any other plugin installed(need to try upgrade plugins as wel as jenkins core), it works for me

you also can check logs

`Dashboard -> Manage Jenkins -> System Log -> All Jenkins Logs`

and add custom logger

`Dashboard -> Manage Jenkins -> System Log -> Add new log recorder`

Name: hudson.triggers.Trigger
Logger: hudson.triggers.Trigger
Log level: All